# How can I connect with a SQL Server 2000

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2000, ado

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2000 that I installed in a Virtualbox W2K machine using C# Express 2015 and OLEDB but was not possible.

Does someone know if it is possible? If not what, .net version is compatible with SQL Server 2000?
Thanks.
Valerio.

Comment: Might be useful [link SQL 2000 .NET 4.5](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3d1eeeda-bcb0-456b-928a-af489b39af4d/error-connecting-to-sql-server-2000-database-using-systemdatasqlclientsqlconnection-after?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: Please find [OLEDB](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/) and [ODBC](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver/) Connection strings to SQL Server 2000, at [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)